# How to trigger refresh of deeply nested child components

Tags: reactjs

I have a deeply nested component hierarchy(think 5 components containing each other), now I might do some backend request in one of the nested (child) components. After this I want to refresh the data on the parent, so everything shows the new data.
For only one hierarchy step I used to pass a refresh method, that could be called from the child.
But for deeper nestings this seems to be error prone and not the right way.
Any tip on how to handle this correctly?
I read somewhere I could use the context api but this did not seem like the right way to me, but I might be mistaken here, any thoughts?

Comment: Context Api is indeed the way to do it, other thing you could try which is still very popular is Redux - https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: I know redux, the thing why I did not use it was, because then I would need to have the loading of data possibly duplicated in a child component. Do you know of any examples how to smth like this with the context api?

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of it this way : In react, you don't want to "trigger a refresh", that's react's job.
You want to tell react that this piece of UI depends on this piece of data, and let it worry about renders.

You can achieve this by having a single source of truth regarding data (context, redux, useReducer hook are three interesting options). You then need to subscribe to data update within components, however deeply nested they are (generally via hooks).

***EDIT***

Yes I did not quite understand your question ! Here is an other attempt :-)

So basically you use the useState hook to store your state in the parent component, pass down that state via props to child components, and make one of the nested children perform a call to your backend.

When you have just one or two levels of hierarchy, it works fine by passing a function to update that state, but you have noticed that this way doesn’t scale when you have deeply nested children.

In my opinion, you need a single source of truth for your data. Passing state via props is not a good solution because the nested components don’t have a way to actually update your data.

You should look into Redux. Your use case is actually the reason I used it for the first time (and I’m pretty sure most people as well).

All your state is in an object that you can access from any component in the hierarchy, and the beauty of it is that any component can send updates.

Of course, if you update the state object (store) from any component, any other component that uses the data gets updated.

Check out [the excellent tutorial by Dan Abramov](https://egghead.io/courses/fundamentals-of-redux-course-from-dan-abramov-bd5cc867) who teaches you how to think in a redux way.

Also, [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) is a library that will allow you to use redux while writing a lot less code.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I want to trigger a reload of data in the backend. I'm using the useState hooks, for local data storage that works fine. But I for example have a parent component load the user data. A child components mutates them in the backend, but then the parent component needs to reload that data, to also show it the right way in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, I did not understand ! I edited my answer.